# Ionic crosswalk configuration to build x86 apk

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I am developing ionic application. Using Crosswalk for the smooth performance in lower versions of android. I can successfully build but i only got a single APK file of armv7. Actually i need multiple APK file of armv7 and x86.

Following is the command used for installing Crosswalk

"ionic browser add crosswalk"

Settings in config.xml file

`<preference name="xwalkVersion" value="19+" />
 <preference name="xwalkCommandLine" value="--disable-pull-to-refresh-effect" />
 <preference name="xwalkMode" value="embedded" />
 <preference name="xwalkMultipleApk" value="true" />`

Please help me to solve this issue. What should i do to get multiple apk file as output.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In Ionic documentation, they say that before you needed to set an environnement variable for multiple apk but no longer now. Maybe an outdated version.

http://blog.ionic.io/crosswalk-comes-to-ionic/

For building the apk, I advise you to use :

```
ionic build android
```

And if you don't manage to make it work, you can still use the cordova plugin.
Don't forget to remove the browser.

```
ionic browser revert android
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview
```